# How can I host a game and give someone the IP using the GOG version of Terraria?

Tags: terraria, gog

I have my server and I just want to let someone play with me. But to do that I have to give them my IP and portfoward Terraria.

How can I do this?

I am using the GOG version of Terraria, so I cannot use Steam Multiplayer.

Comment: COG version? Do you mean GoG (Good old Games), or does a "COG" really exist and I don't know about it?

Answer (score 1):

You go to https://www.whatismyip.com/ and copy the address. Whether you need to activate port forwarding or provide a port depends on your router, normally it should work with the standard selected port without issue.

Regarding setting up a port forward, you have to check your routers manual.